# Java create a opposite method (Equation ask)

Tags: java, equation

I have this method:

```
//ternary can only have: 0,1,2
public int getNumber(int[] ternary){
    int lt = ternary.length;
    int number = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < lt; i++){
        int idx = ternary[i];
        number += (idx * Math.pow(-3, i));
    }
    return number;
}
```

And I need a method that does the inverse:

```
public int[] getArray(int n){
    //I need to figure out how to find the size of array
    //And how to invert that equation.
}
```

Comment: that does not seems much logic... opposite method can return multiple arrays that give same `int` as a result

Comment: this looks like some weird way of conversion between numbers of base 3 and numbers of base 10... But I don't get why the base in `Math,pow(-3,i)` is negative...

Comment: so if you have 2*3^3 + 5*3 + 15 you get 84 and by inverse you mean the decomposition of 84 in ANY possible base?

Comment: yes is base -3. I agree about the weird.

Comment: This is called: a "redundant" representation, as the base is negative and a given value may have different representations. So, the size of the array vary.

Comment: ternary: Only 0,1,2 is possible inside of array

Comment: @AhmadWabbi I think a redundant representation would say that the possible digits can be negative as well as positive, but not the base, doesn't it?

Comment: @ParkerHalo You are right. The comment of the OP about the possible values of the digits came after my comment. This is not redundant.

Comment: @Guilherme Are you sure that you can represent any number this way?

Comment: This looks like a homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you sure that you can represent any number this way? No, I'm not but I believe.

Comment: What have you tried so far? So, I am lost. I know that: number = sum(array[i] * (-3)^i). my first question  is how to invert this equation to get i? I dont really know.

Comment: @Guilherme Of course. Easily provable by induction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a homework question, so you have to work on it on your own.

Here's a hint.

Let `p = n / 9` and `q = n % 9`. Note that `n = p * 9 + q`.

Now let `t = q` if `q < 3` and `q - 9` if `q >= 3`.
Also `s = p` if `q < 3` and `p + 1` if `q >= 3`.

Note again that `n = s * 9 + t`.

`t` results in values `0`, `1`, `2`, `-3`, `-2`, `-1`, `-6`, `-5`, `-4` which are easily mapped to to digits `00` ... `22`. This gives you two last digits. You're left with `s * 9` for first digits.

I hope you can get it from here on your own.